# Faster Web to Python Communication

Tags: python, flask, robotics

I am using a flask app to controll a robot via and arduino. It works like this.

```
Web Interface <--> Flask server and robot code <--> Arduino powered robot
```

I am using a simple html form to send text commands. The problem is, for a robot, submitting html forms is not quite a fast enough form of communication. I would like to keep the remote web-based for portability(I want to be able to use it on a both my computer and my iPhone from the same LAN).

So the question is, is there a faster way for my python script to communicate with my webapp?

Comment: What is the "communication"? What parts of the message are based on _external_ constraints (e.g. what message interfaces you _must_ use)?

Comment: I created a simple message parser. I simply need to send text.

Comment: So you are sending text commands to robot via flask server or the other way round?

Comment: Both ways, I am both sending commands to the robot, and sending sensor data back to the webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know what leads you to believe that the process of submitting web forms is the problem. Without that information, it is difficult to suggest anything at all.

About the best I can suggest is that if you keep a persistent connection, both sides could send each other json fragments over the one connection, thus avoiding the overhead of creating a connection each time.

Another alternative, if your data are simple, is toencode them in the url.

Comment: I think a persistant connection is just what I need. Seems like it would be a great deal faster. Encoding the data in the URL is an interesting solution though.